# Any ideas on how to create a flying tile 3D transition just via script/classes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Right guys,

I have been looking all over the internet for a tutorial to which will show me how to re-create this effect on images...

http://flash-effects.com/tutorial-image-transition-flying-tile-3d/

I dont want to install these 3rd party components, because the project I am working on at present, may in future need to be edited by other designers/developers.

Is there anyway to do this just via scripting???

Any feedback would be appreciated, im ideally looking for a tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you're looking for is [here](http://flashgameu.com/book_source_files_2.html). Then download the Bitmap.zip example and look through it. Although I will reiterate what the page says, you really should buy the book. It's quite good and teaches a lot about Flash in general, not just game programming.

You'd still have to figure out how to randomize the height and width of the pieces, add an onClickListener, and then move the pieces. From the example you provided it looks like they're just moving them back and forth in a z-dimension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is that book directed exclusively at Flash IDE projects?  Looks like a good resource anyhow but I'm in eclipse 99% of the time or at the command line, so if they cater to pure AS3 projects or Flex projects I'm definitely interested.

Comment: Yeah, it's written to be used with Flash IDE. Although, you could write the code in Flex that sets up the initial conditions that he has on the stage for each project, but that'd be kind of a pain probably.